# How to chose between "get" and "have got"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, verbs, possessives

In a class context, would a student, asking about the homework and if any homework is due for today, ask:

> Did we get any homework for today?

or

> Have we got any homework for today?

Or can both questions be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all, I should clarify that there are two forms of the verb here that are often confused:

- "have gotten" -- This is the *present perfect* form of "get".  It implies something has happened (but may be continuing to happen) at some (unspecified) point in the past.
- "have got" -- This is an idiomatic (not grammatically correct but frequently used to the point of being accepted) phrase which is basically *present* tense and equivalent to "do have".

It's actually not clear to me which one you intended to use in the above examples, so I'll talk about both, so we've got three possibilities:

> Did we get any homework for today?
>
> Have we gotten any homework for today?
>
> Have we got any homework for today?

Now, in the case, because the time of the event (today) has been explicitly specified, the "did we get" and "have we gotten" are pretty much interchangeable, and both can be used more or less in the same way.  However, that's not always the case.

If the time is not specified, the two have somewhat different meanings.  "did we get" is the *simple past* tense, meaning that it implies a specific instance that happened (and concluded) in the past.  However, as mentioned, "have we gotten" is much more vague about the time frame it's talking about.  In particular, with "get"/"gotten", the *present perfect* usually implies "ever" or "before".  As an example:

> **Alice:** Did you get homework in English class?
>
> **Bob:** No, the teacher let us off easy today.

vs.

> **Alice:** Have you gotten homework in English class?
>
> **Bob:** Yeah, she's given us lots every day since the class started.  Luckily, today she let us off easy.

So that's "did get" vs. "have gotten".  What about the last case ("have we got")?  Well, that's *present* tense, so what it's actually asking is "Do we have any homework for today?".

In many cases, this is effectively the same thing, but not always.  If, for example, there's some standard homework exercise for the class that always needs to be done every day, then yes, you have homework for today, but no, you didn't get it today.

> **Alice:** Have you got homework in English class?
>
> **Bob:** Yeah, we didn't get any homework assigned today, but we always have to do our vocabulary exercises anyway.

So, getting back to your original question:

Yes, both questions can be used.  Yes, they both sound fine.  Yes, in many cases they mean the same thing **but** sometimes they may have different implications in terms of the exact timing of events.

Comment: *Have got* most certainly ***is*** grammatical. And it's grammatical in both US and UK English. On the other hand, *have gotten* is mostly considered ungrammatical in UK English. *Have gotten* is, for the most part, really only used in US English. (And while it's probably used more often than *have got* in US English, *have got* is still completely valid.) So, you have your explanations reversed in the first part of your answer.

Comment: I will admit that I hadn't realized this was one of those things that is notably different between US and UK English.  However, I do maintain that my description was correct (and not reversed) for the case of US English: "have gotten" and "have got" do *not* mean the same thing in US English: "have gotten" is past tense, whereas "have got" is pretty much always used as a present tense construction in the US despite the use of the past-tense "got" in its construction (which is why it's technically ungrammatical, and will get you points off from most English teachers).

Comment: You claim that *have got* is "not grammatically correct." That's simply not true. Of the two, it's the only version that *is* grammatical in both regions of English. If there's anything ungrammatical, it's *have gotten* in UK English.